# how use timer, to create a stopwatch without gui/jframe?

Tags: java, stopwatch

```
package primer;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

@Component
public class SocketTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) 

            throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        String clientMessage = message.getPayload();
        if (clientMessage.startsWith("start")) {    
            
        for (int h = 0; h < 60; h++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
                    for (int s = 0; s < 60; s++){
                        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(
                            String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s)));
                            
                        Thread.sleep(1000);                                                                 
                    }       }           
                }
            } if (clientMessage.startsWith("stop")) {
                
            }
                    
                }       }
```

This is the `socketTextHandler` code that responds to messages sent from the client to the server.

The question is, the counter should be one for everyone, i.e. multiple clients see the same counter value, regardless of when the client typed start.

How to implement it? If you make it static, how? Or make one global counter on the server, which is launched by the first client and already subsequent clients, if you enter start, it shows the current counter. In principle, I can imagine how to implement this, but I don’t know by what methods. Hours of scrolled forums and Google did not give any knowledge.
UPD
when server get `start`, server will respond to client many messages like : 00:00:01, 00:00:02...
i wanted to doesnt matter how much client writed `start` they all need to see value of first client timer

tried to static whole cycle, but then `sendMessage` can't reach "h, m, s" value.

Comment: Have you tried using `AtomicInteger` as a counter? because each client will start their own thread.

Comment: What use is a stopwatch when you can't account for internet latency?

Comment: Explain: If client A comes at first and sends "start", and 20 seconds later, client B comes and sends "start", should client B see "20" or "1"?

Comment: @RealSkeptic client B should see 20.

Comment: And do they get one message or how many? In short, [edit] your question, and add an explanation of what the inputs and the outputs are. "A client comes in and sends `start`, the system is supposed  to give them such and such report such and such times" etc.

Comment: @damjad idk what it is, began to reading about

Comment: "the counter should be one for everyone" - consider modeling the counter as its own object.  Create a singleton instance for each of the components that need to share it.